# TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects

Tags: python, semaphore

Esto me da

**TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects**

Por qué? ayuda.

Me hace fala saber porque incluso he cambiado la versión del interprete y nada todavía

```
import random
import multiprocessing
import time


class ActivePool:

    def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()
        self.mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
        self.active = self.mgr.list()
        self.lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    def makeActive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.append(name)

    def makeInactive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.remove(name)

    def __str__(self):
        with self.lock:
            return str(self.active)


def worker(s, pool):
    name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
    with s:
        pool.makeActive(name)
        print('Activating {} now running {}'.format(
            name, pool))
        time.sleep(random.random())
        pool.makeInactive(name)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = ActivePool()
    s = multiprocessing.Semaphore(3)
    jobs = [
        multiprocessing.Process(
            target=worker,
            name=str(i),
            args=(s, pool),
        )
        for i in range(10)
    ]

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()

    while True:
        alive = 0
        for j in jobs:
            if j.is_alive():
                alive += 1
                j.join(timeout=0.1)
                print('Now running {}'.format(pool))
        if alive == 0:
            # all done
            break
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el error completo?¿Se refiere a la variable `pool`?

Comment: TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects esta es la salida. Necesito que alguien me explique y que me ayude a solucionar este error.